# Find the sequence of integers that satisfies a recursive condition.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

> We have a natural number $n\geq4$ and the set A= {$a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$} with natural numbers. We know $a_{k}+k\sqrt{a_{k+1}} \in A $ for every $k \in \{{1,2,...,n-2}\}$. We also know that $a_{1}<a_{2}<...<a_{n}$. Knowing that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ is a perfect square, find $A$.

So we have $a_{k}+k\sqrt{a_{k+1}}=a_{q}$. We can easily see that $q>k$ so $a_{q}>a_{k}$ for a fixed k. Also we find out that $k\sqrt{a_{k+1}}$ is a natural number so $a_{k+1}$ is a perfect square for every $k \in \{1,2,3,...,n-2 \}$. From here we can say $a_{2},a_{3},...,a_{n-1}$ are perfect squares. Another interesting thing is the fact that $a_{n-2}+(n-2)\sqrt{a_{n-1}} \in \{a_{n-1},a_{n}\}$. Let's say $a_{k}=p_{k}^{2}$, for $k \in \{2,3,...,n-1\}$, and $p_{k}$ a natural number. Obviously if $i>j$, then $p_{i}>p_{j}$. Let's say $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}=P^{2}$, where $P$ is a natural number. We have $a_{1}+a_{n}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}p_{k}^{2}=P$. This is where I got stuck. Can someone give me an idea/hint?

Comment: Do you consider $0$ a natural number?

Comment: @Servaes I know number theorists say that 0 is not a natural number, but because this is a problem for 7/8 graders, I think we can say 0 is natural as they are taught. But I don't know how this question is relevant to this problem.

Comment: Opinions differ on whether $0\in\Bbb{N}$. (Any number theorist I know uses the convention $0\in\Bbb{N}$). If $0\notin\Bbb{N}$ you can immediately conclude that $a_1\geq1$, and from there quite quickly that $a_k\geq k^2$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$. If $0\in\Bbb{N}$ then you only get $a_k\geq(k-1)^2$. Makes quite a difference in how good or bad the algebra turn out, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Servaes FYI, re: $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ for this question is a moot point as it only makes a difference if $a_1 = 0$. In that case, for $k=1$, we get $a_k+k\sqrt{a_{k+1}}=\sqrt{a_2}\in A$. Due to $a_i$ being strictly increasing, this means $\sqrt{a_2}=a_2\;\to\;a_2=1$. For $k=2$, we then get $1+2\sqrt{a_3}\in A$, so $a_3$ must be of the form $j^2$ for some $j \ge 2$. If $a_3=4$, then $5 \in A$, but for $j \ge 3$, then $a_2\lt 1+2\sqrt{a_3}\lt a_3$, so it's not possible. Thus, then $n=4$ with $A=\{0,1,4,5\}$, but $\sum_{k=1}^{4}a_k=10$ is *not* a perfect square, so it's not a solution.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, eliminating $a_1=0$ is even better. This doesn't seem like a problem for 7/8 graders though.

Comment: @Servaes FYI, using the fairly strict limits that the ordering of $a_k$ and that most of them are perfect squares, I determined a solution and wrote an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4726838), with it showing there is actually just one set $A$. Although my detailed explanation is fairly long, the math involved is actually fairly simple, so I suspect it should likely not be an issue for any students at the $7$/$8$ grade level.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the $a_i$ sequence being strictly increasing, as you already noted, we have

$$a_{k}+k\sqrt{a_{k+1}}=a_{q} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

with $q \gt k$. Note that, as $k$ increases, $q - k$ is a non-decreasing function. Thus, since $q \le n$ at $k = n-2$, then $q-k$ is always either $1$ or $2$. For $k = 1$, consider if

$$a_{1}+\sqrt{a_{2}} = a_{3} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $a_{2}$ and $a_{3}$ are both perfect squares, and $a_{3} \gt a_{2}$, we then have

$$\sqrt{a_{3}} = \sqrt{a_{2}} + j_{2}, \;\; j_2 \ge 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Substituting this into \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_{1}+\sqrt{a_{2}} & = (\sqrt{a_{2}} + j_2)^2 \\
a_{1}+\sqrt{a_{2}} & = a_{2} + 2j_2\sqrt{a_{2}} + j_2^2 \\
a_{1} & = a_{2} + (2j_2 - 1)\sqrt{a_{2}} + j_2^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

However, since $(2j_2 - 1)\sqrt{a_{2}} \gt 0$ and $j_2^2 \gt 0$, then \eqref{eq4A} indicates that $a_{1} \gt a_{2}$, contradicting the requirement $a_{2} \gt a_{1}$. Thus, we must instead have that

$$a_1 + \sqrt{a_2} = a_2 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Next, consider if

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_2 + 2\sqrt{a_3} & = a_3 \\
a_2 + 1 & = a_3 - 2\sqrt{a_3} + 1 \\
a_2 + 1 & = (\sqrt{a_3} - 1)^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

However, $0$ is the only perfect square that, when $1$ is added to it, gives another perfect square. Since $a_2 \gt 0$, this is not possible. Thus, we must instead have

$$a_2 + 2\sqrt{a_3} = a_4 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

If $n \gt 4$, then $a_4$ must be a perfect square so, similar to \eqref{eq3A}, we get

$$\sqrt{a_4} = \sqrt{a_3} + j_3, \;\; j_3 \ge 1 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq7A} results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_2 + 2\sqrt{a_3} & = (\sqrt{a_3} + j_3)^2 \\
a_2 + 2\sqrt{a_3} & = a_3 + 2j_3\sqrt{a_3} + j_3^2 \\
a_2 & = a_3 + 2(j_3-1)\sqrt{a_3} + j_3^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Since $2(j_3-1)\sqrt{a_3} \ge 0$ and $j_3^2 \gt 0$, this gives $a_2 \gt a_3$, which is not allowed. Thus, $a_4$ can't be a perfect square, so $n = 4$. Next, we have

$$a_4 = a_3 + j_4, \;\; j_4 \ge 1 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq7A} gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a_2 & = (a_3 + j_4) - 2\sqrt{a_3} \\
& = (a_3 - 2\sqrt{a_3} + 1) + j_4 - 1 \\
& = (\sqrt{a_3} - 1)^2 + j_4 - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Since $\sqrt{a_3} - 1 \ge \sqrt{a_2} \;\;\to\;\; (\sqrt{a_3} - 1)^2 \ge a_2$ and $j_4 - 1 \ge 0$, we must have

$$\sqrt{a_3} = \sqrt{a_2} + 1, \;\; j_4 = 1 \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

With $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=m^2$ for some integer $m$, and letting $\sqrt{a_2} = r$ for simpler algebra, then using \eqref{eq5A}, \eqref{eq10A} and \eqref{eq12A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
m^2 & = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 \\
& = (a_2 - \sqrt{a_2}) + a_2 + (\sqrt{a_2} + 1)^2 + ((\sqrt{a_2} + 1)^2 + 1) \\
& = (r^2 - r) + r^2 + (r + 1)^2 + ((r + 1)^2 + 1) \\
& = 4r^2 + 3r + 3
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

Since for $r \gt 0$ we have $(2r)^2$ being too small and $(2r+2)^2 = 4r^2 + 8r + 4$ being too large, the only possibility is $m = 2r+1 \;\;\to\;\; m^2 = 4r^2 + 4r + 1$, so

$$4r^2 + 4r + 1 = 4r^2 + 3r + 3 \;\;\to\;\; r = 2 \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

Thus, $a_1 = 2^2 - 2 = 2$, $a_2 = 2^2 = 4$, $a_3 = (2 + 1)^2 = 9$ and $a_4 = 9 + 1 = 10$, giving that $A = \{2, 4, 9, 10\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Interesting answer!